# open div without the hash in the address bar

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, hash, anchor

I want to open an anchor div on my website when a user surfs to a link without the # in the address bar. **For example**; when a user goes to www.website.com/nameofdiv it has to auto open the div with the same anchor tag name (www.website.com/#nameofdiv)

I use the following script to open and close anchor div's on my website:

```
 function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('.show').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).fadeIn(500);
      }
      else {
           $(this).fadeOut(500);
      }
 });
 }
```

This is the HTML click event i am using:

```
<a href="#nameofdiv" onClick="javascript:slideonlyone('nameofdiv');">link</a>
```

I tried some stuff with the .htaccess and with the next script but it didnt worked.

```
 window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'');
```

I hope I explained it well enough and I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Are you using PHP or ISIS? Sounds like you're looking for a `rewrite` which is pretty easy to do, though you'll still use the hash tag in the redirect, rewrite can change the address to look like whatever you please

Comment: @SpYk3HH i am using PHP!

Comment: Ok, the next question is important, because hashtags are not rewritten server-side. Are you wanting the `anchor` links to appear on the page without hashtags and then rewrite them when going to that location, or are you looking to simply remove the hashtag from the address bar when a link is clicked on? The difference: `a href="some.com#divID --addressbar--> some.com/divID` |OR| `a href="some.com/divID --addressbar--> some.com#divID`? |OR| possibly `a href="some.com/divID --addressbar--> some.com/divID`? All very different solutions

Comment: @SpYk3HH I eddited my question, maybe it's a bit more clear now? :)

Comment: its plenty clear, i dont quite have time to answer it at moment, i'm out and about. I'll come back as soon as I can. until then, 2 things to look at, `apache rewrite` and `window.history.pushState`

Answer (score 4):

If you're calling that code from a `click` handler, make sure you `return false` from the click handler, or call `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I think what he's looking for is an `.htaccess` rewrite type solution

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I still can't seem to make it work, I also changed my question a bit, maybe that makes my question a bit more clear. Hope you can help